# Is cakephp support file upload without plugin?

Tags: cakephp, file-upload

As the title, is cakephp support file upload without uses of plugin or not ?

**I means any code that made by cakephp developers not include pure php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Cakephp is support file upload, I just have to set the name of form to use it.

Comment: That's what I meant by implementing your own logic.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, for a full implementation you will need a plugin or create your own logic. Cake does offer convenience methods based on the base PHP functions. The [File & Folder](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html) utility is an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use component instead of plugin like [this one](https://github.com/tute/Thumbnail-component-for-CakePHP/) and it should do the job, but I'm not sure is this what you are looking for.

Comment: Tasks like this belong into the model layer and that component is a pretty poor one.